# Como uma variável ponteiro para inteiro é armazenada?

Tags: c

Quando declaramos :

`int* x;`

Como que o compilador compila isso e como o computador (seria melhor dizer sistema operacional, pois é ele que gerencia a memória) executa isso ?

Digo, o S.O. reserva um espaço na memória para armazenar um endereço de memória do tipo `int` e dá o nome à ela de `x`. 
Mas como ele faz isso ? Tem alguma flag na própria memória que diz que aceita só inteiros ? Caso fosse um endereço para `char` o que mudaria ? E como ele sabe que o nome dela é `x` ? Seria uma outra flag ?

Grato.

Comment: Pergunta relacionada: [O que são e onde estão o “stack” e “heap”?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/74)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso funciona pela tabela de simbolos. Quando voce faz

```
int *x;
```

o compilador vai nessa tabela, aloca um espaco de 4 bytes na memoria e associa o endereco desse local com o nome `x` e o tipo `int *`.

Entao a tabela fica algo como:

```
x    0xff843af int *
```

Se fosse um `char`, como nao e nada mais que um numero tambem, o seu programa interpreta o valor do byte como `char`.

Comment: Então logo que o programa começa a ser executado, o S.O. cria uma tabela para saber quem é quem ? E no caso de variáveis locais de mesmo nome de variáveis globais ? (Está errado dizer que o S.O. que executa ?)

Comment: nao e o SO que cuida da tabela de simbolos, e o compilador. o SO gerencia a memoria do sistema 'de forma geral'.

Comment: Toda vez que eu vou executar um programa ele vai chamar o compilador para cuidar da tabela de símbolos ? Achei isso estranho..

Comment: Nao, o compilador depois de gerar o executavel nao vai mais usar a tabela, ela so e usada durante a compilacao.

Comment: Ok, mas e depois de compilado ? Toda vez que eu executar meu programa ele vai ter de alocar memória para as variáveis, como isso funciona ? (Não precisa entrar na questão de stack e heap, somente a parte das variáveis)

Comment: as variaveis vao ser alocadas nas paginas que o SO der para o programa. como o programa sabe os tipos, ele sabe computar os enderecos e usar.

Comment: Para ponteiros o computador sempre aloca o mesmo tamanho, somente para o endereço ser colocado. A grosso modo, um ponteiro não necessitaria de um tipo ao ser declarado, isso só ocorre por segurança de código. Endereços são do mesmo tamanho, então o computador sabe o tamanho para alocar no caso de ponteiros.